# inner_join or merge remain second id colum

Tags: r

I have conducted an inner_join or merge function in R.
I want to remain the second id column "DI" in the result.

```
library(dplyr)
ab<-data.frame(ID=(c("PDM.999993856","PDM.999960488")),oi=rep("r",2),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
to<-data.frame(DI=c("PDM.999993856","PDM.999960488"),kl=rep("foo",2),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
inner_join(ab,to, by=c("ID"="DI"))
```

Comment: `merge(to,ab,by.x = "DI",by.y = "ID",all.y = T)` , This Helps ?

Comment: Isn't that completely redundant information?

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
 to %>% 
   mutate(ID = DI) %>% 
   inner_join(., ab, by = "ID")
```